# Reference Request: Neighbor-avoiding sets of flags

Tags: reference-request, finite-fields, flag-varieties

Let $K$ be a finite field and $\mathcal{F}$ the set of full flags in $K^n$, i.e. $\mathcal{F}$ consists of chains of subspaces
$$0 < V_1 < V_2 < V_3 < \ldots < V_{n-1} < K^n$$
such that $\dim(V_i) = i$. Every such chain is called a flag. Two such flags are called **neighbors** if they only differ in a single space.
I recently found a way to construct some big subsets $M \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ having a nice structure (e.g. fast membership test) such that no two elements of $M$ are neighbors and now I'm wondering:

> Is there anything known about such sets? Does there exist some interest in the topic, are there people working on it, do you know of papers dealing with similar questions?

Comment: The $\mathbb{F}_1$-version of this question is to construct a big subset of the symmetric group which contains no two neighbors in the permutohedron order (i.e., two permutations that differ only by a transposition of adjacent entries). Of course, the maximum size of such a subset is reached by the alternating group. Are yours also this large? Maybe "fixing the value of the sign" translates into "fixing the value of the Steinberg character of the representing matrix" in some way.

Comment: I may be well off here, but (a wild guess) may be some such combinatorial properties of flags come to the fore in their applications to network coding.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are not off at all, that is indeed how I got to this topic. :)  
I was just wondering if there is some other approach for it.  
darijgrinberg: I'm far from reaching index two in the set $\mathcal{F}$. In fact, I'm not even that close to the sphere packing bound for such sets yet. That is also one reason why I'm looking for other work on that, to compare how "good" my sets really are.  
I will try to check the Bruhat cells that appear here, maybe I cover the whole alternating group in this way, thanks for the hint.